# How can i solve $\frac{x^2}{a}-\frac{x}{b}-\ln(x)=0$

Tags: logarithms, quadratics, wolfram-alpha

How can i solve: $$\frac{x^2}{a}-\frac{x}{b}-\ln(x)=0$$ for any pair $(a,b)$?

For example, if $a=29$ and $b=7$, wolframalpha gives me: $$x= 0.903969\ldots$$  $$x= 10.6013\ldots$$ but it wont show me how the calculation is done. 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2F29-x%2F7-ln(x)%3D0

Comment: The calculation is done numerically.  There is no known "closed form" solution in general.

Comment: @RobertIsrael that would explain why calculation is not shown...

Comment: can we solve it by linearizing the equation? like expanding $\ln x$ in a Taylor Series and then considering the first term of the series only?

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya That would not "solve" it, but will provide an approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in comments, you will need some numerical method.

Consider that you look ffor the zero(s) of function $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{a}-\frac{x}{b}-\ln(x)$$ for which 
$$f'(x)=\frac{2 x}{a}-\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{x}\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\frac{2}{a}+\frac{1}{x^2}$$ As in your case, let us assume $a$ and $b$ to be positive.

This makes $f''(x)>0 \,\, \forall x$ and the first derivative cancels at a point $x_*$ given by
$$x_*=\frac{a+\sqrt{a(a+8 b^2)}}{4 b}$$ $$ f(x_*)=\frac 12-\frac{a +\sqrt{a(a+8 b^2)}}{8 b^2}-\log \left(\frac{a+ \sqrt{a(a+8
   b^2)}}{4 b}\right)$$ If $f(x_*) <0$, there will be two roots such that $0 < x_1 < x_*$ and $x_2 > x_*$; otherwise, no real root to the problem..

With this information, we can now consider using Newton method using, for example, as starting points $x_0=\frac{x_*}4$ and $x_0=4x_*$.

Trying for your specific example, for the first root, the iterates will be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.2454852120 \\
 1 & 0.8454663552 \\
 2 & 0.9020694730 \\
 3 & 0.9039667915 \\
 4 & 0.9039687574
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, for the second root
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 19.92776339 \\
 1 & 13.27849976 \\
 2 & 10.98937363 \\
 3 & 10.61245701 \\
 4 & 10.60133991 \\
 5 & 10.60133017
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solution for ten significant figures.

For sure, you can have much better estimates if you start graphing the function.

**Update**

At least for the largest root (when it does exist), we can have a good estimation using a Taylor series around $x_*$. Ignoring the higher order terms, this would give
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*) (x-x_*)^2+O((x-x_*)^2)$$ from which
$$x_{est}=x_* +\sqrt{-\frac{2f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$

Applied to the example, this would give $x_{est}\approx 10.1546$ and the following iterates for Newton method

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 10.15464106 \\
 1 & 10.61836864 \\
 2 & 10.60135298 \\
 3 & 10.60133017
\end{array}
\right)$$